# HTML form not clearing after submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I have a contact form on my website and I want the form to clear out once a user clicks the "submit" button.

The form sends the data to a Google Sheet upon submission. I have this part working correctly.

The piece I cannot seem to get working correctly is clearing the form upon clicking "submit".

I've tried many different options to get the form to successfully reset after clicking "submit" and nothing seems to work.

Also, the script contains a `console.log` success message when correctly submitting the form without error. This has not been showing in my Dev Console even though the form is successfully sending the data to the Google Sheet. Not sure if this is related to my error?

```js
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxx/exec'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(scriptURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new FormData(form)
  }).then(response => {
    console.log('Success!', response)
    form.reset();
  }).catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
```

```html
<section class="section-form" id="contact">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Join Our Campaign</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <form id="google_form" name="submit-to-google-sheet" method="post" action="#" class="contact-form">
      <!-- ------- NAME ------- -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="ex: John Doe" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ------- EMAIL ------- -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="ex: hello@gmail.com" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ------- PHONE NUMBER ------- -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <input type="tel" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" id="phone" placeholder="ex: 555-555-5555">
        </div>
        <!-- ------- ZIP CODE ------- -->
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <input type="tel" name="zipcode" pattern="[0-9]{5}" id="zipcode" placeholder="ex: 78701" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ------- HOW DID YOU FIND US? ------- -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <label for="find-us">How did you find us?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <select name="find-us" id="find-us">
            <option value="friends" selected>Friends</option>
            <option value="search">Search engine</option>
            <option value="ad">Advertisement</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ------- NEWSLETTER ------- -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <label for="news">Newsletter</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="news" checked> Yes, please
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ------- DROP US A LINE ------- -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <label>Drop us a line</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <label>&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
          <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Poease share your attempts to clear the form. "Nothing seems to work" is a bit broad

Comment: It's because `form` is out of scope here: `form.reset();`. If you do `console.log(form);` here it'll return you undefined. Try `document.getElementById('google_form').reset();` here instead.

Comment: @icecub form is a global const - at least is looks that way in the posted code

Comment: @mplungjan Hmm you're right. Though I've had issues with that before in a callback function. Ah well, my bad :)

Comment: I am not super convinced by your .then in your fetch. Have a compare with  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Your reset is working fine when you take it out of the `fetch` API call, so your issue is somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with your calling URL, make sure to check your requested resource, if you are looking for that, there is no success while requesting resource, so that's why your form is not resetting.

check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/byajLkcr/)

```js
const scriptURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  const form = document.forms['myForm'];

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   fetch(scriptURL, { 
   method: 'POST',
   body: new FormData(form)
   }).then(response => {
   //console.log('Success!', response);
   form.reset();
   alert('cleared');
  }).catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Reset form" button to reset the form.</p>

<form id="myForm">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Reset form">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried out your test code and I only receive the first alert. Here's what I have: ```form.addEventListener('submit', e => {  
          alert(3);  
          e.preventDefault()  
          fetch(scriptURL, {  
            method: 'POST',  
            body: new FormData(form)  
          }).then(response => {  
            console.log('Success!', response)  
            form.reset();  
            alert('cleared');  
          }).catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))  
      })```

Comment: The first `alert(3)` worked but the `console.log` and the `alert('cleared')` did nothing. I wonder if there's a problem at the Fetch part?

Comment: it is working fine for me, did you try running embedded code.

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/23dquyxn/ , it is working perfectly without issues.

Comment: Your code works brilliantly when I copy+paste it into a standalone HTML project with just the contact form. But for some reason it fails as part of my larger project. I even copy+pasted your code into my project to confirm and it still fails, so perhaps the issue is elsewhere in my code. What's odd is it's still sending to the Google Sheet this entire time without issue, just not clearing from the page.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct because it does work for this specific question I asked. I'm going to then dive into my project deeper to see why it's not working. Perhaps some of the other jQuery or JS I'm using is interfering with it and preventing it from running successfully.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. For some reason moving ` form.reset();` at the end of the script (after the catch error part) fixed the problem. No idea why that worked, but it did!

Comment: You likely do not want to reset if there was an error since the user might want to modify to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem of function processing competition. Very common in javascript. You can opt for the setTimeOut function which sets a time to perform the function, preventing function processing competition.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

The code tested looked like this:

```
    <script >
    const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxx/exec'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch(scriptURL, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new FormData(form)
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('Success!', response)
            setTimeout(function() {
                form.reset();
            }, 2000);
        }).catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
    }) 
</script>
```

Comment: Try this, and talk about the result, please